# Prove that the area of $S\cap B$ doesn't depend on R

Tags: calculus, integration

Given $S=\{x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2\}$ and $B=\{x^2+y^2+(z-R)^2<r^2\}$ Prove that the area of $S\cap B$ doesn't depend on R

I've tried

$G=S\cap B=\{x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2,z>R-\frac{r^2}{2R}\}$.
$\int_G=1dvol_3=\int_{R-\frac{r^2}{2R}}^{R}\int_{x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2}1dxdydz=\int_{R-\frac{r^2}{2R}}^{R}2\pi\sqrt{R^2-z^2}dz=*$
where $\int_{x^2+y^2=R^2-z^2=t^2}1dxdy=\int_{t\mathbb{S}^1}1dvol_1=t\omega_2=2\pi\sqrt{R^2-z^2}$
I've got stuck on * maybe there is an easier way to solve this?

Comment: The statement looks wrong. As $R \to 0$ the area of $S$, hence that of $S \cap B$, tends to $0$.  If the area is independent of $R$ then it must be $0$ for all $R$ but that is not true.

Comment: What is connection between $r$ and $R$?

Comment: this question from an exam I just copied and tried before :(

Comment: Put $x=0$, you'll come on plane. Then take $r=R$ and $r=R/2$ - area will be same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is not correct. We should consider two distinct cases:

1. If $0<r\leq 2R$ then $S\cap B$ is the [spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#Deriving_the_surface_area_intuitively_from_the_spherical_sector_volume) of a sphere of radius $R$ and height $h$ such that $(r/2)/R=h/r$, that is $h=r^2/(2R)$. Therefore its area is
   $$\text{Area}(S\cap B)=2\pi R\, h=\pi r^2.$$
2. If $0<2R<r$ then $S\cap B=S$ and
   $$\text{Area}(S\cap B)=4\pi R^2.$$

Comment: So the area does depend on $R$ and it does go to $0$ as $R \to 0$ , as I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy if we assume that $R,r>0$  does it cahnge the answer?